# Deploy windows phone app on multiple devices the same time

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, nfc

I'm working on an NFC game at the moment. For testing, I of course need two devices, so I borrowed the Lumia 1020 of my dad. Together with my 820, I've got two NFC-capable devices. The problem is that for testing the app, I can't plug in both phones the same time in my PC, because VS complains that multiple devices are plugged in, but rather I have to plug in the first one, install the app, unplug it, plug in the second one, press F5 and start up the app on the second device. As this slows me down quize a lot, my question is: is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a second pc you could think of plugging a device in each PC, syncing the code through an SVN and have a quasi-parallel deployment that should save you some time, especially if you do clean deployments and not incremental ones.

Comment: Well. Uhm... not quite what I thought about, but seems that's the only method. I think I'll stick to deply one after another:)